# argparse.argumentparser parsing argument string which contain '|' character

Tags: python, argparse

My python script is called with the arguments with following argument

```
script.py -p "{\"script_args\": \"pass_string=TEST RESULT|PASS;cmd_args=Option_1#1,Option_2#7\\r;\"}" -port_no 1234
```

in my script.py

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process input arguments.')
parser.add_argument("-p", "--testcase_params", action="store", type=str,
                    dest='TestcaseParams', required=True,
                    help="Testcase Parameters")
parser.add_argument("--port_no", action="store", type=str,
                    dest='port_no', required=True,
                    help="Port No for Py4J Gateway Server")
ARGS = vars(parser.parse_args())
```

While argument for -p can be any string. When this string contains '|' as in above option or '&' I am getting **"'PASS' is not recognized as an internal or external command"** error.

Is '|' is used by the **argparse** module as a separator?
Can someone give some idea on how to solve this?

Comment: This is your shell giving you that error message, not Python.

Comment: This is a **shel escaping issue**, not a Python problem.

Comment: Thanks I am new to scripting will check how to solve this as the argument to the string is from the another system which I can't control